# iOs Install Test App - iOs 7.1 and iPhone 5s

Tags: testing, cordova, ios7, iphone-5

I've developed a Phonegap App. Now I'm tryng to release it to some BetaTester.

I've followed the procedure described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) and successfully installed on an iPhone 4s with iOs 7.1 and on an iPad2 with iOs 7.1 but I can't install it on an iPhone 5s with iOs 7.1

After the sinc end withot any error the app icon remains faded in grey with a label "Installing..."

I triple checked to have added the UDID to the provisioning profile, and I thought that iTunes will throw an error anyway if the device is not correctly listed. So... I have no Idea on how to fix this...

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way [How to Test Your App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6wHeh0f5vQ)

this will helps you

Comment: Thanks, I haven't find out where the error was but following this procedure had fixed it.